# Implications of Weak/Strong Nullstellensatz Theorems

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Towards the end of my commutative algebra class, my prof stated and proved the weak/strong nullstellensatz theorems. The weak nullstellensatz was given as:

> Let $k$ be a field and $R$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. If $R$ is a field, then $R$ is a finite algebraic extension,

and the statement of the strong nullstellensatz is:

> Suppose $R$ is Jacobson and $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra.
> (1) $S$ is Jacobson,
> (2) If $m\subseteq S$ is a maximal ideal, then $f^{-1}(m)\subseteq R$ is maximal, and
> (3) $R/f^{-1}(m)\subseteq S/m$ is a finite extension.
> \end{enumerate}

I think I understand the equivalence of the two statements with the different (equivalent) statements of these theorems, but I don't quite know the importance of them or how they are used. I know there is a relation to algebraic geometry, but I am more focused on the "commutative algebra" viewpoint right now. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: For starters you can use them to exactly characterize the maximal ideals of a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field. Very concrete and very important consequence.

Comment: Oh I guess those maximal ideals would be of the form $\langle x_1-\alpha_1,\dots,x_n-\alpha_n\rangle$ for some $\alpha_i\in k$, and for that you would use the inclusion from $k$ to $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/p$ for some maximal $p$.

Comment: Very good. Sometimes it’s this result that goes by the name of the Nullstellensatz.